# Alternative for Serial type in RedShift / PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key, auto-increment, rails-postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am actually trying to make Rails working with RedShift, and facing some issue with Rails default indexes. My work is based on the repo activerecord-redshift-adapter.

By default, Rails use the SERIAL type to create his primary key. Unfortunately, this is unsuported by RedShift. So I am actually trying to find an alternative to this SERIAL type, and then fork the repo once we found a viable solution. I am thinking about a BIGINT, from what [RedShift offer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html).

The line to be changed is situated here [redshit_adaptated.rb (Line 252)](https://github.com/fiksu/activerecord-redshift-adapter/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/redshift_adapter.rb#L252).

Any proposition, better solution?

Comment: How do you intend to *generate* that sequence? Does Redshift still have `CREATE SEQUENCE`? Because if so - `SERIAL` is just a convenience pseudo type that can be replaced with `CREATE SEQUENCE`, then creation of a table with a bigint column with `default nextval('sequence_name')` and finally `ALTER SEQUENCE .. OWNED BY`.

Comment: I don't know actually how to generate the sequence, that is the question.RedShift does not support ([see Sequence manipulation functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)) `CREATE SEQUENCE`, which make sense if SERIAL is just a convention for this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try having identity column created so that Redshift generates the sequence numbers. If you want to retain existing Rails serial numbers, then start with identity from that max number may be.

Answer (score 0):

The straight replacement for the `SERIAL` is `IDENTITY(seed, step)` 
Reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html